# linq to sql lambda - syntax for not in where condition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql

I want to use '!' to exclude the following records in my .Where.

What is the syntax?

```
// where do I put the ! to get the syntax correct
.Where(p => p.StartDate >= startDate && p.EndDate <= DateTime.Now.Date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Where(p => !(p.StartDate >= startDate && p.EndDate <= DateTime.Now.Date))
```

OR

```
.Where(p => p.StartDate < startDate || p.EndDate > DateTime.Now.Date)
```